# Matlab package: graphical calculus for quantum operations including beam splitters and polarizing beam splitters

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, software

I need a matlab package that will make my life easier. I have quantum circuits with optical beam splitters, polarizing beam splitters and photodetectors. These circuits are getting very complicated and I am wondering if anyone knows of a matlab package that would make my life easier. A graphical package would be excellent and I suppose any software will do.

Comment: I'd be interested in helping to develop open source Python software for that...

Comment: Cross-listed from TP.SE http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/907/189