# Matlab package: graphical calculus for quantum operations (esp. linear optics)

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, software

I need a matlab package that will make my life easier.  I have quantum circuits with optical beam splitters, polarizing beam splitters and photodetectors.  These circuits are getting very complicated and I am wondering if anyone knows of a matlab package that would make my life easier.  A graphical package would be excellent and I suppose any software will do.

Comment: Beyond the [qotoolbox](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Quantum_Optics_Toolbox), which is showing its age but still very useful, I'm not sure what to suggest. A graphical package does not exist (as far as I'm aware), and is not likely to unless you make it yourself since this not in high demand.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Make it an answer.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: Done. Bit sad to have such a negative answer, but you are right that it is one.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20773/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond the [qotoolbox](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Quantum_Optics_Toolbox), which is showing its age but still very useful, I'm not sure what to suggest. A graphical package does not exist (as far as I'm aware), and is not likely to unless you make it yourself since this not in high demand.

Comment: Sze Tan did not believe in function prototypes when coding in C. It works, just don't go poking around in the source code.